# Trouble calling batch file from Java program

Tags: java, file, batch-file, command

Everything I read says that the only way to call a batch file from within a java program is to do something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batch.bat");
```

From what I understand this creates a process to run CMD.exe, which in turn creates a process to run the batch file.  However, the CMD.exe process appears to exit once it has instantiated the batch file process.

**How can I confirm that the batch file has completed before the CMD process exits?**

Comment: You should be using `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exe()` now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jeb said, or try passing the `/wait` parameter to `start`. That should cause `start` to wait till the batch process completes. Try it at the command line first -- faster than rebuilding your Java app.

Comment: I agree with you that `start /wait` should work, but with the `/wait` switch the start will be completly unnecessary.

Comment: I would think so, but maybe the OP needs it to be in a separate window? Note: I'm not a batch file expert. :)

Comment: It seems that leaving "start" out causes the program to hang. I have no clue as to why.

Comment: This is the best solution, although it only works if "start" is left in.

Answer (score 3):

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batch.bat");

To wait for the batch file to finish (exit) you remove the "start" after the `/c`.
The `/c` tells cmd.exe to return when cmd is finished, this you want, however, "start" means start a new cmd.exe process to execute the batch file. At this point the cmd.exe you started is finished and exits. Probably not what you want.

Either of the two code snippets below will get the batch file running and get you a Process object that you will need.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c batch.bat");
```

Or

```
ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder ("cmd", "/c", "batch.bat");
    Process p = pb.start ();
```

Now that you have a Process object you have multiple ways to wait for your batch file to finish.

The simplest way is .waitFor()

```
int batchExitCode = -1;
try {
  batchExitCode = p.waitFor ();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // kill batch and re-throw the interrupt
  p.destroy (); // could also use p.destroyForcibly ()
  Thread.currentThread ().interrupt ();
}
```

You could also use `waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` or `p.isAlive()` if they meet your needs better.

**Warning** If your batch is going to output a lot of data (probably more than 1024 characters, maybe less) to stdout and / or stderr your program needs to handle this data in some manner, otherwise, the pipe (s) between your program and the batch process will fill up and the batch file will hang waiting for room in the pipe to add new characters and the batch file will never return.

This is the problem that originally brought me to Stack Overflow this time. I had 17,000+ commands in a batch file and each command generated 300+ characters to stdout and any errors executing a command generated 1000+ characters.

Some of the ways to solve this:

1. `@echo off` as the 1st line in the batch file, with this the cmd process will not echo each command in the batch file. If your batch file does not generate any other output to stdout or stderr you are done.
2. If one or more of the commands in the batch file can or may generate a lot of stdout and / or stderr output then you have to handle that data yourself.
3. If you are using "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" you only have one way to handle this and that is to get the InputStreams for the batch file's stdout and stderr by calling:

   ```
       InputStream outIS = p.getInputStream (); // this gets the batch file's stdout
       InputStream errIS = p.getErrorStream (); // this gets the batch file's stderr
   ```

   Now you have to read each of the InputStreams (only when they have data or you will wait until you do). Assuming that you get a lot more data from one of the InputStreams than the other you are almost assured of hanging the batch file. There are ways to read multiple streams without hanging, however, they are beyond the scope of my already excessively long answer.
4. If you are using `ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder ("cmd", "/c", "batch.bat");` (and this is a major reason to do so) you have a lot more options available to you since you can ask for stdout and stderr to be combined `pb.redirectErrorStream (true);`, easier to handle one InputStream without blocking, or you can redirect stdout and stderr to files (null files may work on Windows definitely on Unix) so you program doesn't have to handle them.
5. Don't forget that if your batch file reads data from stdin, you have to handle that as well. This is supported in **Process** and with more options in **ProcessBuilder**.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to start the batch without the "start" command after cmd /c, as the "start.exe" creates a new process for the batch.bat.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c batch.bat");
```

This should be the correct form for you.

Comment: Right but you wish to confirm the cmd completed you need to add `p.waitFor();`

Comment: Or you could try to read the p.exitValue(), if you didn't want to block your thread

Comment: If I exclude the start, the whole program hangs.

Comment: when you start cmd /c it does not display the console. Check with the task manager if the process is running. If you want to display the console try `cmd /c start /wait cmd /c batch.bat`. I succesfully run this test `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait cmd /c \"c:\\batch.bat > %temp%\\out\"");
  p.waitFor();`

Answer (score 1):

From the output of `cmd /?`

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Thus what you need is:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start batch.bat");
```

Comment: But then cmd.exe never ends. And the batch.bat is running in an other process at all ( as it is started by start.exe)

Comment: That is wrong. "Start
Starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command. Used without parameters, start opens a second command prompt window.". You should not use 'start' in this case.

Comment: Excluding "start" causes my program to hang. Why is this?

Comment: Possibly the batch process never finishes? What happens when you run the batch file from the command line with the same args/flags you're passing into `exec()`?

Comment: The batch file runs fine alone, so I'm not really sure

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply find out whether the batch file process finished or not, why not add...

```
echo DONE
```

at the end of the batch file?

Or if you program is for public use, something like...

```
echo finished>log.txt
```

would work. Then verify that it is finished from within your java program...

```
if (new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt")).readLine().equals("finished"))
{
    System.out.println("the batch process has finished");
}
```

Comment: Well, the idea was to check if the batch file finished so that I could run another command before the cmd.exe process terminated.

Comment: Also, the contents of the batch file are user-defined. Essentially, I'm making a batch file editor (with some special features).